# Facing ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED in NextJS

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js, openssl

I tried deploying my old code via vercel but it threw me this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI5Wk.png)

My package.json file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjDeP.png)

I am not sure what to do :(

I wanted to try adding in the flag "--openssl-legacy-provider" but not sure on how to implement it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.